# What is the term for a column in a matrix with one 1 and the rest 0s?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, terminology

I'm wondering what the mathematical term for a column in a matrix with one 1 and the rest 0s is. Is it called a unit column or something like that?

Comment: There's no term that I know of. If I heard "unit column", I would tend to assume that it meant the column had unit length (which the column described certainly does, but other column vectors could have unit length as well).

Comment: At https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_named_matrices, it says that a Single-entry matrix is  "A matrix where a single element is one and the rest of the elements are zero." This motivates possibly calling it a "Single-entry Column".

Also at that page, it seems that Permutation matrix satisfies the condition you had.

Comment: Thinking of columns as vectors and matrix multiplication as a linear combination of the columns, I would think of those columns as the basis vectors, but I'm not sure anyone calls them that.